# Iterate values of a map using range-based for loop

Tags: c++

Recently I started using range-based for loop. I had a problem where I needed to sort a map by value and then check if value is smaller/larger then some other element/number. Can I do that with this loop?

```
for (auto& it : M){
    // assign only a value to vector
}
```

This question would be the same if I had a vector of pairs, could I just check for second, if it is larger then some other element or number? All this using range-based for loop.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if ranged-for applies to maps?

Comment: You can't sort a map. It has it's own idea of the correct order of its elements.

Comment: Here is some example:  'for (auto& it : M) {
        // code
    }'  Can I find the sum of values using range-based loop?

Comment: Did you mean to copy the values to a vector and sort the vector?

Comment: `variable_name = it->second;`?

Comment: All standard containers have a `value_type` alias. For [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) it's defined as `std::pair<const Key, T>`. It's this `value_type` that you get references to in your ranged loop. So the name `it` is misleading because it's not an iterator, it's a *value*.

Comment: An iterator through a map dereferences to a `std::pair`. You can do `for (auto [k, v]& : M) { my_vector.push_back(v); }` to add just the values.

Comment: A `std::map` is naturally sorted, because it’s a red-black tree. You can supply your own comparator to influence the sorting order, but that’s all you can do. `std::unordered_map` has no guaranteed sorting order, because it is a hash table, and (IIUC) the iteration order is not even guaranteed to be the same during repeated iterations over the same (unmodified) map (although this happens to be the case in known implementations). If you want to sort a `std::unordered_map`, you need to transform it into (e.g.) a `std::vector` and then sort it or into a `std::map` which is sorted by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C++20, you can use [views::values](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/values_view) to get at the values of a `std::map`, or a `vector<pair>` for that matter:

```
for (auto v : m | std::views::values)  // m is some map
  // ...
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ecrro9rMx)

You can similarly get at the keys with `views::keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Example using C++20 views to show only those entries in the map of which the value is greater then 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>

std::map<std::string, int> my_map
{
    {"one", 1},
    {"two", 2},
    {"three", 3},
    {"four", 4}
};

int main()
{

    // create a lambda predicate (a predicate is a function that returns a bool)
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
    auto greater_then_2 = [](const auto& pair)
    {
        // use structured binding for readability 
        // (I don't like std::pairs at all for maintainability)
        // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding
    
        auto [key, value] = pair; // key = pair.first, value = pair.second

        // evaluate predicate
        return value > 2;
    };

    // now loop over all pairs in the map and filter them (C++20 feature)
    // combine structured binding with range based for loops and filters
    for (const auto& [key, value] : my_map | std::views::filter(greater_then_2))
    {
        std::cout << "key = " << key << ", value = " << value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```